# How to iterate over two dictionaries and save them in a list in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to iterate over two dictionaries `d = {'d': 2, 'c': 6, 'a': 1, 'b': 3}` and `d2 = {'j': 9, 'b': 5, 'a': 2, 'k': 10}`. It should store values like 
`[[key1, value1 value2], [key1, value1, value2], [key2, value1, value2]...]` 
First, trying to store `d` values in a `my_list` as `my_list = [d[keys], d[values], 0]`.

My code is as below,

```
my_list = []
for i, j in d.items():
if i in my_list:
    print(i, "is in list")
else:
    my_list.append([i,j,0])

output: my_list = [['d', 2, 0], ['c', 6, 0], ['a', 1, 0], ['b', 3, 0]]
```

Then, iterate over `d2` and if key of `d2` exists in `my_list` then replace `0` with `d2[values]` else add it to `my_list` like `[d2[keys], 0, d2[values]]`.

When I check `'d' in my_list`, it gives me `False` and `True` for `'d' in my_list[0][0]`.

So, to get `my_list[0][0]` position, I've used another `for loop` something like,

```
for k in range(len(d2)):
    for i, j in d2.items():
        if i in my_list[k][0]:
            my_list[k][2] = d2[j]
        else:
            my_list.append([i,0,j])
```

which gives me error,

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#505>", line 4, in <module>
    my_list[k][2] = d2[j]
KeyError: 2
```

What I am missing here?

Can anyone please tell me how to add keys and their values without duplicating in a list?

Thank you

Comment: Could you pls provide the desired output?

Comment: It should be like 
[[key1, value1 value2], [key1, value1, value2], [key2, value1, value2]...]

Comment: You have used an example input right. Provide the desired output for that. Few confusions with what exactly you want. Seeing the Output will clear those.

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: @ Kaushik
d = {'d': 2, 'c': 6, 'a': 1, 'b': 3}
d2 = {'d': 9, 'b': 5, 'a': 2, 'k': 10}

output: [[d,2,9], [c,6,0], [a,1,2], [b,3,5], [k,0, 10]]

Comment: @RaúlReguilloCarmona 3.4

Comment: Keep in mind that the keys of these dictionaries are sets (in the mathematical sense).  Python has set operators for union, intersection, difference and symmetrical difference; use those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can form the result in three steps. First create a list containing keys that exists on both dicts by creating intersection of the keys. Then add keys that exist only first one and finally add the keys that are only on second dict.

```
d = {'d': 2, 'c': 6, 'a': 1, 'b': 3}
d2 = {'d': 9, 'b': 5, 'a': 2, 'k': 10}

result = [[k, d[k], d2[k]] for k in d.keys() & d2.keys()]
result.extend([k, d[k], 0] for k in d if k not in d2)
result.extend([k, 0, d2[k]] for k in d2 if k not in d)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[['b', 3, 5], ['d', 2, 9], ['a', 1, 2], ['c', 6, 0], ['k', 0, 10]]
```

You could do this with union and [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) as well:

```
>>> d = {'d': 2, 'c': 6, 'a': 1, 'b': 3}
>>> d2 = {'d': 9, 'b': 5, 'a': 2, 'k': 10}
>>> [[k, d.get(k, 0), d2.get(k, 0)] for k in d.keys() | d2.keys()]
[['k', 0, 10], ['c', 6, 0], ['d', 2, 9], ['a', 1, 2], ['b', 3, 5]]
```

As @JimDennis noted above only works with Python 3 since on Python 2 [`keys`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) returns a list instead. This can be mitigated by constructing a set from the return values:

```
[[k, d.get(k, 0), d2.get(k, 0)] for k in set(d.iterkeys()) | set(d2.iterkeys())]
```

Comment: Wow!!. This is brilliant.
Thank you very much niemmi.

Comment: Might want to comment on the use of the set intersection operator on those .keys() results ... and note that this is Python3 specific.  In older versions of Python you have to call set(d1.keys()) & set(d2.keys())) to explicitly render the .keys() into sets.

Comment: I did ... I just wanted the comment to be up here near the question.  It's worth bearing in mind every time one is using dictionary keys.

Answer (score 1):

This would do

```
d = {'d': 2, 'c': 6, 'a': 1, 'b': 3} 
d2 = {'j': 9, 'b': 5, 'a': 2, 'k': 10}

list=[]
for key,value in d.iteritems():
  if key in d2:
    list.append([key,d[key],d2[key]])
  else:
    list.append([key,d[key],0])

for key,value in d2.iteritems():
  if key not in d:
    list.append([key,0,d2[key]])

print list
```

Output:

```
[['a', 1, 2], ['c', 6, 0], ['b', 3, 5], ['d', 2, 0], ['k', 0, 10], ['j', 0, 9]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Following works :

```
l=[]                                           #store desired output
#go through elements of First dictionary (d1)
for key,val in d1.items(): 
   try: 
     #create the list and pop the element in d2 that matched with key of d1 
     temp = [key,val,d2.pop(key)] 
   except: 
     temp = [key,val,0] 
   l.append(temp) 

#print(l)
#[['d', 2, 9], ['c', 6, 0], ['a', 1, 2], ['b', 3, 5]]

#d2 may have elements left, go through them
for key,val in d2.items():
  temp=[key,0,val]
  l.append(temp)

print(l)
```

#driver values

```
IN : d1= {'d': 2, 'c': 6, 'a': 1, 'b': 3}
IN : d2 = {'d': 9, 'b': 5, 'a': 2, 'k': 10}
OUT: [['d', 2, 9], ['c', 6, 0], ['a', 1, 2], ['b', 3, 5], ['k', 0, 10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary keys in Python are sets (in the mathematical sense).  In Python3 they are set like objects and can be used with Python's set operators.

In earlier versions of Python the dictionary *.keys()* method returns a list and this must be explicitly converted to a *set()* in order to use the set operators/methods on them.

So a simple function to your stated requirements is as simple as:

```
def merge_dicts_to_list(this, that):
    common = set(this.keys()) & set(that.keys())
    these  = set(this.keys()) - set(that.keys())
    those  = set(that.keys()) - set(this.keys())
    results = [[k, this[k], that[k]] for k in common]
    results.extend([[k, this[k]] for k in these])
    results.extend([[k, that[k]] for k in those])
    return results
```

I'll grant that "this" and "that" ... "these" and "those" are not the most inspired variable names ("left" and "right" might be more conventional. "d" and "d1" are harder to read).

This example is deliberately verbose. I originally wrote it as three lines but decided that the complexity of those set expressions was harder to read and reason about.  This way it should be fairly clear.  The intersection are the keys in common, the set different each way gives those keys which are only found in one or the other; and we simply build a list of lists using those sets of keys.

In general it is far too common for programmers to forget about sets and set operators; they then end up re-implementing code to perform these operations creating more code to maintain, more opportunities for their own errors, and missing on the probably performance benefits of using the features built into their language.

Comment: Also keeping sets in mind will help when you're working with SQL as it's based on set operations.